# Wait until T seconds before chrome web loading scroll is done selenium python 3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

By chrome web loading scroll I mean the dynamic loading icon at any chrome tab.

I need a kind of "WebDriverWait" to return an error if the loading icon from chrome doesn't stop scrolling until T seconds. Using pure WebDriverWait for checking the presence of some element would not be worth for me as WebDriverWait would just run after scrolling is done and I need to check if the selenium commands are already running (that's when scrolling is done). I tried to do this by using the method `set_page_load_timeout`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://apps.varejonline.com.br/relatorios/relatorios/base/analisevendasperiodo/0')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(2) #I've set a time of 2 seconds just to test this methods
```

But this pages cleary takes (loading scroll is done) more than 2 seconds to load so `driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)` would supposed to me return an error but it didn't. Is this method outdated? How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are loading the page before setting the page loading timeout hence a timeout exception will not be thrown after the 2 seconds

What you want is: set the page loading time **before** loading the page and execute the loading in a `try...except` statement to catch when the loading is timed out

```
def load_page(url: str, timeout: int = 20):
    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
        driver.get(url)
        return 'Loading Page Successful'
    except TimeoutException:
        return 'Loading Page Failed'
```

Alternatively, you could change the [PageLoadStrategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy) of the driver. There are three strategies: `normal`, `eager` and `none`. Default is `normal`. This holds off all other driver activities until the page is ready. From my experience, I prefer using the `eager` strategy which then allows me to use `WebDriverWait` to check for readiness of elements on the page

Change the loadstrategy via the chrome options

```
options.set_capability('pageLoadStrategy', 'eager')
```

Then load your page and use WebDriverWait to check the elements on the page

Complete code method 1:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def load_page(driver: Chrome, url: str, timeout: int = 20):
    try:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
        driver.get(url)
        return 'Loading Page Successful'
    except TimeoutException:
        return ''
    finally:
        # reset the page load time, not necessary
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(1) # use default


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    url = 'https://apps.varejonline.com.br/relatorios/relatorios/base/analisevendasperiodo/0' # this url is not responding
    loaded = load_page(driver, url, 60)
    if not loaded:
        print(f'the page {url} is taking too long to load')
        # quit or do something else
    else:
        print('Page loaded')
        # search your elements, continue crawling

    driver.quit()
```

Complete code Method 2:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def find_element(driver: Chrome, locator: tuple[str, str], timeout: int = 40):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        return element
    except TimeoutException:
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.set_capability('pageLoadStrategy', 'eager')

    driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    url = 'https://apps.varejonline.com.br/relatorios/relatorios/base/analisevendasperiodo/0' # this url is not responding
    driver.get(url)
    element = find_element(driver, (By.XPATH, '/html/path/to/element'), 30)
    if not element:
        print('Element not found')
    else:
        print(element.get_attribute('innerText'))

    driver.quit()
```